# How do I store a vector of float vectors in shared memory in C++?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, shared-memory

I am need to store a vector of float vectors in shared memory in C++. I have a toy example that works, for storing an integer in shared memory. This is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int pid;
    int start = 0;
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    key = 123;
    int *shm;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }   

    shm = (int *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0)
    {   
        wait(NULL);
        cout << *shm << *(shm+1);
    }   
    else if (pid == 0)
    {    
        *shm = 6;
        *(shm+1) = 7;
    }   
    else
    {
        exit(-1);
    }   

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, it is my understanding that this is much harder with the datatype vector> instead of a simple integer. Do I need to write a custom allocator (and if so, are there any simple ways to do this? The examples I have found have all been pretty complicated...) to make this work, or is there a simple extension of this example that will let me place a vector> in shared memory?

Comment: Check out Boost.Interprocess.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is actually a homework assignment that explicitly mentions "do not use Boost". I was just wondering if there was a clean way to do this...

Comment: You'll need to de-/serialize your vector's contents!

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more, I don't follow...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store a `std::vector<T>` in a shared memory region, because the actual elements inside the vector aren't stored within the memory of `std::vector<T>`, but are allocated on the heap.

Technically, you could construct your own [`allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator), but I would think that it's easier to simply serialize the content of your vector.

Something like this:

```
vector<float> vec_f;
// some code fills vec_f .. 
float *shm;
shm = (float *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

for(auto f : vec_f)
{
   *shm++ = f;
}
```

(Or, if you don't want to use C++ style iteration)

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec_f.size(); i++)
{
    *shm++ = vec_f[i];
}
```